# How to prevent gcc optimizing in kernel modules?

Tags: optimization, module, kernel, pragma

I'm trying to understand how can one disable code optimization for kernel modules when compiling with gcc.
I tried giving pragmas like this

```
#pragma optimize("",off)
void rt_ct_use_cpu(unsigned long long n_cicle){
    unsigned long long i;
    for(i=0;i<n_cicle;i++);
}
#pragma optimize("",on)
```

But the compiler gives a warning saying that it is going to ignore those pragmas. I also tried making something that avoid the compiler to roll the loop like

```
void rt_ct_use_cpu(unsigned long long n_cicle){
    unsigned long long i;
    unsigned long long time=0;
    unsigned long long timebase = rt_get_cpu_time_ns();
    for(i=0;i<n_cicle;i++) {
        time += rt_get_cpu_time_ns();
        time -= timebase;
    }
}
```

but in this case it doesn't matter how long is the cicle (how big is n_cicle) the program will run always the same amount of time (few milliseconds)

Can you help me?

Comment: Could you perhaps compile these files with -O0  ?

Comment: Alternatively, see section 7.3.1.1 of this page http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-7-sect-3  if a busy-loop is what you really want. If you just want to delay execution for a period of time it's better in most cases to use the delay/sleep functions instead.

Comment: You are awesome man! Your solution using the delay functions works brilliantly! Thank you very much!

Comment: adding volatile keyword to the variable time and/or timebase also prevents GCC from optimizing the delay loop

Answer (score 3):

See GCC pragma documentation [6.59.13 Function Specific Option Pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html)
like in `#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot or at least you should not do that in Linux kernel. At least -O1 is required to ensure that the inliner and other essential optimizators run. For example, some assembly code like the `setjmp` function must be inlined or they won't execute correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe things have changed, but I just added -O0 to my kernel module Makefile and it was able to build and run and I can debug with it and nothing gets optimized out and the debugger can show all the variables, and trace line by line in the expected order.